# Footnote with an image but without the marker

Tags: footnotes

While inserting an image in the footnote, it is duplicated as marker besides the main text. I want to remove the marker but also want to keep the image in footnote. If I use `\footnote{\includegraphics[height=5.0mm]{image.png} text here}`, then a number and image both pop up beside the text as marker. If I use `\blfootnote{\includegraphics[height=5.0mm]{image.png} text here}`, the number in the marker goes away but the image still remains. How do I remove both the number and image from the marker?

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.